Why is my question downvoted?
Did people comment on Yukio Mishima's sexuality while he was alive?

History Stack Exchange is for historians and history buffs. If you have a question about:


Historical events
Cultures and historical practices
Famous people
Ancient Languages
Human Prehistory
Factual current political history questions
Historiography


Then you are in the right place.

(Emphasis added)
Yukio Mishima is a known author, near-Nobel-Prize winner, coup-attempter, and seppuku-doer.
Many academics have commented on Mishima's sexuality. Many think it influences his work (for example, in the two novels I listed in my question). Yet in his roughly 20 year career I can't find a single person, in Japan or abroad, to have publicly made the connection between his work and his sexuality while he was alive. Confessions of a Mask was published in English (and presumably the USA) in 1958, just a few years after the US Lavender Scare.
I'm wondering what I did wrong for this question to not be welcome here (i.e. downvoted). If I could find the information myself, I would have. It is not readily available on Google or Wikipedia, or even a cursory review of Google Scholar. I am not a historian nor literature expert so I posted the question.

The stuff you listed is what makes a question on-topic here, not what makes the question good. If people thought it violated one of those, it would be getting close votes, not (just) downvotes.

If you added some of the information about your research which you have listed in your question here, I suspected your question on the main HistSE site might not have attracted some of those downvotes. You have clearly done prior research (which we require and appreciate), but that is not so obvious from your original question.

@LarsBosteen You should make that an answer. I find it completely plausible that this is a reason for the downvoters.

In general, people's votes are their business, and they can make them for any reason they want. * Of course making a post on-topic here does not guarantee people will like said post.
If its something fixable with edits, and the voter feels like the poster would be open to hearing criticism, then its nice form to leave a comment explaining the perceived problem. But that's effort, and is quite often soundly punished by the post creator, so most people won't bother to do that. Actual criticism is (usually) a gift.
So you just have to look at the comments you did get, and beyond that try to objectively look at what you wrote and see if there's anything that might set somebody off.
In this case the comments that were left don't strike me as downvote-level issues, so it probably wasn't them.
One of our more dedicated users (and now a volunteer moderator. Thanks for your service!) has kindly posted a list of their most common reasons for downvoting posts : Why did my question get a downvote?, so that may be a good resource. I don't see an obvious connection there with this question, but its a great resource and worth looking over if you struggle to write good questions in general.
Everything from here down is speculation of course, but there are some other possible issues I see.
In particular, I know anytime I find myself having to post something that may contain content that clashes with someone's political or religious beliefs, I can count on getting some downvotes. For example, this answer of mine I thought was rather good. However, the first vote it got was a downvote, and about 1/3rd its current votes now are downvotes. I'm not surprised, as its directly challenging the validity a historical belief that US-based (white) people have liked to hold, largely for political reasons, since before the Civil War. Sometimes you just have to put on your grownup pants, tighten your belt, and take a few hits for The Truth.
In the case of this question you mentioned, we know many people consider non-cis-het human sexuality to be fundamentally against their core Religious and/or Political beliefs. I could see downvotes on this question from such a person, mad that its even being discussed. I could also see downvotes from a non-cis-het person who feels the question isn't being asked in a measured respectful manner, or is not coming from a place of support. He appears to have been a political figure, so I could see a position where someone doesn't want their (apparently far-right) political views tarred with lots of talk of his sexuality.
Another thing I'm noticing is that the question seems to be a self-answer. Those are allowed, but controversial. Often its a really good way to get down here an answer to an important question, which can perhaps be used later to close (as duplicates) weaker related questions that may come up. Obviously the more likely it is to be a question someone else will have at some point, the more valuable it is.
However, some have tried to use self-answers in the past as a cheap way of pumping their site reputation. The more trivial the question, the more likely someone is to look at it that way. Given this is the first I've ever heard of this person, I'm guessing a lot of others here haven't either. Looking over his bio, I don't see where he did much that would impact someone who wasn't Japanese. So I could see where someone might feel this was perhaps a question with a somewhat sexually lurid (clickbaity) subject on a trivial matter intended only to artificially boost the author's site rep, without actually contributing much of value to anyone else.
This is all speculation though. It could just be several people hate Tripods.

* - There are limits of course. In particular, just deciding you don't like someone and going through their account in an hour downvoting every post you find is a good way to get your account suspended.

Obligatory not a downvoter, but...
Some people do not like questions in which you aim to answer it straightaway. I know StackExchange allows this, but I've seen complaints before arguing that it's reputation-farming or just disingenuous.
Personally, I too don't like those questions (and virtually never find them useful or interesting to me), though that doesn't often translate into a downvote; plenty of questions are perfectly fine but not interesting to me, so I simply don't consider that an option. However, others could be more trigger happy. It's difficult to say.
Just like TED's answer, take this as speculation about your question. Votes are regularly mysterious, so it's good you came here to ask about it. Maybe someone who downvoted will explain their reasoning.
